# Path does not exist "keys" for ssh-password-storage-path

Tags: rundeck

When specifying a new node with the ssh-password-storage-path in Rundeck 2.4.0 with the path keys/projects/${job.project}/nodes/${node.name}/rundeck.password, Rundeck is unable to find the path with the error below:

> 2015-03-06 10:14:59,088 [Thread-97] ERROR com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.steps.node.NodeStepPluginAdapter - Error executing node step.
>   com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.steps.node.NodeStepException: com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.service.FileCopierException: Configuration error: Failed to read SSH Password stored at path: keys/projects/Test/nodes/WindowsNode/rundeck.password
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.plugin.copyfile.CopyFileNodeStepPlugin.executeNodeStep(CopyFileNodeStepPlugin.java:59)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.steps.node.NodeStepPluginAdapter.executeNodeStep(NodeStepPluginAdapter.java:106)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.ExecutionServiceImpl.executeNodeStep(ExecutionServiceImpl.java:149)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.dispatch.SequentialNodeDispatcher.dispatch(SequentialNodeDispatcher.java:116)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.dispatch.SequentialNodeDispatcher.dispatch(SequentialNodeDispatcher.java:58)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.ExecutionServiceImpl.dispatchToNodes(ExecutionServiceImpl.java:177)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.steps.NodeDispatchStepExecutor.executeWorkflowStep(NodeDispatchStepExecutor.java:66)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.ExecutionServiceImpl.executeStep(ExecutionServiceImpl.java:116)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.BaseWorkflowStrategy.executeWFItem(BaseWorkflowStrategy.java:166)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.BaseWorkflowStrategy.executeWorkflowItemsForNodeSet(BaseWorkflowStrategy.java:226)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.BaseWorkflowStrategy.executeWorkflowItemsForNodeSet(BaseWorkflowStrategy.java:193)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.StepFirstWorkflowStrategy.executeWorkflowImpl(StepFirstWorkflowStrategy.java:79)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.BaseWorkflowStrategy.executeWorkflow(BaseWorkflowStrategy.java:124)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.NodeFirstWorkflowStrategy$DispatchedWorkflow.dispatch(NodeFirstWorkflowStrategy.java:366)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.dispatch.SequentialNodeDispatcher.dispatch(SequentialNodeDispatcher.java:118)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.dispatch.SequentialNodeDispatcher.dispatch(SequentialNodeDispatcher.java:64)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.ExecutionServiceImpl.dispatchToNodes(ExecutionServiceImpl.java:196)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.NodeFirstWorkflowStrategy.executeWFSectionNodeDispatch(NodeFirstWorkflowStrategy.java:178)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.NodeFirstWorkflowStrategy.executeWorkflowImpl(NodeFirstWorkflowStrategy.java:107)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.BaseWorkflowStrategy.executeWorkflow(BaseWorkflowStrategy.java:124)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.WorkflowExecutionServiceThread.run(WorkflowExecutionServiceThread.java:55)
>   Caused by: com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.service.FileCopierException: Configuration error: Failed to read SSH Password stored at path: keys/projects/Test/nodes/WindowsNode/rundeck.password
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.impl.jsch.JschScpFileCopier.copyFile(JschScpFileCopier.java:157)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.impl.jsch.JschScpFileCopier.copyFile(JschScpFileCopier.java:212)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.ExecutionServiceImpl.fileCopyFile(ExecutionServiceImpl.java:261)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.plugin.copyfile.CopyFileNodeStepPlugin.executeNodeStep(CopyFileNodeStepPlugin.java:52)
>           ... 20 more
>   Caused by: com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.tasks.net.SSHTaskBuilder$BuilderException: Failed to read SSH Password stored at path: keys/projects/Test/nodes/WindowsNode/rundeck.password
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.tasks.net.SSHTaskBuilder.configureSSHBase(SSHTaskBuilder.java:572)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.tasks.net.SSHTaskBuilder.buildScp(SSHTaskBuilder.java:628)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.tasks.net.SSHTaskBuilder.buildScp(SSHTaskBuilder.java:608)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.impl.jsch.JschScpFileCopier.copyFile(JschScpFileCopier.java:154)
>           ... 23 more
>   Caused by: org.rundeck.storage.api.StorageException: Path does not exist: keys/projects/Test/nodes/WindowsNode/rundeck.password
>           at org.rundeck.storage.api.StorageException.readException(StorageException.java:37)
>           at org.rundeck.storage.data.file.FileTree.loadResource(FileTree.java:61)
>           at org.rundeck.storage.data.file.FileTree.getResource(FileTree.java:42)
>           at org.rundeck.storage.impl.DelegateTree.getResource(DelegateTree.java:40)
>           at org.rundeck.storage.impl.DelegateTree.getResource(DelegateTree.java:40)
>           at org.rundeck.storage.conf.ListenerTree.getResource(ListenerTree.java:54)
>           at org.rundeck.storage.impl.DelegateTree.getResource(DelegateTree.java:40)
>           at org.rundeck.storage.conf.ConverterTree.getResource(ConverterTree.java:53)
>           at org.rundeck.storage.impl.DelegateTree.getResource(DelegateTree.java:40)
>           at org.rundeck.storage.conf.ConverterTree.getResource(ConverterTree.java:53)
>           at org.rundeck.storage.impl.DelegateTree.getResource(DelegateTree.java:40)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.storage.AuthRundeckStorageTree.getResource(AuthRundeckStorageTree.java:130)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.storage.AuthRundeckStorageTree.getResource(AuthRundeckStorageTree.java:18)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.storage.ResolvedExtTree.getResource(ResolvedExtTree.java:52)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.impl.jsch.JschNodeExecutor$NodeSSHConnectionInfo.getPasswordStorageData(JschNodeExecutor.java:540)
>           at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.tasks.net.SSHTaskBuilder.configureSSHBase(SSHTaskBuilder.java:563)
>           ... 26 more

Originally, I placed the keys directory under the RDECK_BASE directory, but that does not seem to be the correct place.  Also, putting an absolute path fails with the error 'Configuration error: SSH Password storage path is expected to start with "keys/"'.  Also, trying to add a default storage path through the GUI has an error: 'Path not found: keys'.  Where is the relative path of the keys directory expected to be so I don't try to add a keys directory under every subdirectory on the drive.

Answer (score 3):

If you did a rpm installation, keys will be found in the below location
/var/lib/rundeck/var/storage/content/keys/

If you had moved the keys to another location make sure to set permissions to the user used to run rundeck using **chown** and **chmod** commands

Comment: @btz
If you saved the password from UI in a folder structure as below **projects/${job.project}/nodes/${node.name}/rundeck.password**
, use the below in node configuration
ssh-password-storage-path="keys/projects/${job.project}/nodes/${node.name}/rundeck.password".


Kindly share a screenshot in rundeck UI where you have saved you pass/key